# Exclamation mark moves from end to start when reading cells with Arabic text with the Google Sheets API

Tags: unicode, google-sheets-api, arabic, right-to-left

I'm using the Google Sheets API to export cells that contain Arabic text to a JSON file. When a cell contains text that has an exclamation mark at the end of a sentence (so on the left side of the text in an [RTL cell](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65166)), it switches positions in the API response and ends up on the right (incorrect) side in my resulting JSON output:

```
  "levelSelect:titleOne": "قاوم الطعام غير الصحي!"
```

The word order is correct, but I would expect the exclamation mark to be after the third double quote from the left and not before the fourth one. The punctuation mark placement is correct in the original cell in Google Sheets:

[image]

So all the Unicode RTL characters are coming back in the original order, but the one non Unicode character (the exclamation mark) has switched places.

I query Google Sheets with a [higher level library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spreadsheet-to-json), but even if I make a direct API request (using the [OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)), I get the same output (FWIW, it makes the request with `charset=utf-8` in the `Content-type` header). The order is already wrong before I write the response to a file.

At this point, I am not sure if this is a bug in the Google Sheets API, or there is something fundamental I don't understand about how Arabic text should be handled. There doesn't seem to be a magic 'format this mostly Unicode string with the non Unicode characters in the right place' conversion function.

I am aware that there are copy and paste issues bewteen different sources where this can happen when you paste text with formatting from the clipboard. If I copy the cell with Cmd-C (on a Mac) and then paste it into some places with just Cmd-V, I get the reversed order, and if I use Shift-Cmd-V, I get the correct order for the exclamation mark. It's as if what the API sends gets confused here on what format to send.

Comment: Where should the exclamation point actually be ?

Comment: @Aerials: The JSON output I was expecting would mirror the image in the post: `"levelSelect:titleOne": "!قاوم الطعام غير الصحي"`

Comment: Notice when selecting the arabic text and exclamation from you above comment that the selection grabs first the exclamation point, then moves all the way to the right to start getting each character of the RTL text. I also noticed this happens in the sheets editor itself as well with other non unicode characters like ?

Comment: @Aerials Yep, I've noticed that. I assume this is connected to my problem somehow. I've tried inputting the full Unicode character form of an exclamation mark (Option 0021 with the Unicode Hex Input keyboard source enabled on macOS), but that didn't help.

Comment: This might be worth reporting in Issue Tracker, using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191608&template=823917). Have you noticed this behaviour with other characters and with other RTL languages?

Comment: @Iamblichus Thanks for the tip. I have gone ahead and filed an issue there (#183952589) with some sample code to replicate it.